# Web Page Update statement won't update in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

My update statement functions but unfortunately doesn't ACTUALLY update the row in SQL Server. When I check SQL Server, the row is the same as when "profile" was created. Please let me know if any more info is needed besides my update statement.

Here's my code:

```
// Update statement
SqlConnection MyConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["F18_kslchaneconnectionstringLOGIN"].ConnectionString);

string updatestatement = "UPDATE dbo.userprof SET firstu = '"+TextBox1+"', lastu='"+TextBox1+ "', emailu='" + TextBox2 + "',phonenum='" + TextBox3 + "',orgname='" + TextBox4 + "',titleuser='" + TextBox5 + "',deptuser='" + TextBox6 + "', password='" + TextBox7 + "');";

SqlCommand mysqlupdate = new SqlCommand(updatestatement, MyConnection);

// cn.Open();
// string sql = "UPDATE main SET s_name='" + TextBox1.Text + "',inst_code='" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + "',ms_oms='" + Label7.Text + "',elligiblity='" + Label12.Text + "',Board='" + DropDownList5.SelectedItem.Value.ToString() + "',percentage='" + float.Parse(TextBox4.Text) + "',amount='" + Label10.Text + "' WHERE elg_id = " + DropDownList4.SelectedItem.Value + "";

// OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, cn);
// cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
// cmd.Dispose();
// cn.Close();

// mysqlupdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstu", TextBox1.Text);
// mysqlupdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastu", TextBox1.Text);
// mysqlupdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailu", TextBox2.Text);
// mysqlupdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phonenum", TextBox3.Text);
// mysqlupdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@orgname", TextBox4.Text);
// mysqlupdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@titleuser", TextBox5.Text);
// mysqlupdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deptuser", TextBox6.Text);
// mysqlupdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox7.Text);

try
{
    MyConnection.Open();
    // mysqlupdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
    // mysqlupdate.Dispose();

    Label1.Text = "User has been updated!";
}
catch (Exception myexception)
{
    Label1.Text = myexception.Message;
    MyConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: UPDATE without WHERE... like shooting yourself in the foot? And BTW, commented code will not execute

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Look at the end of your update string - there is a rogue `)` closing bracket. Remove that. Uncomment `mysqlupdate.ExecuteNonQuery();`. Add a `WHERE` clause and parameterize your variables

Comment: I don't need a where clause since I want to update all the rows, right?

Comment: *"I want to update all the rows"* - all users with same email address?

Comment: Why even `TextBox1` hasn't a property? mybe `TextBox1.Text`? or it's a variable? that beside to what other has said.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an `SqlCommand` is not enough - you also need to execute it:

```
mysqlupdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
```